# Reducer function passed to useReducer hook is executed multiple times for one dispatch call when reducer function is dependant on a component prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was reading an article called “[A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)” and tried to implement and an example from “[Why useReducer Is the Cheat Mode of Hooks](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#why-usereducer-is-the-cheat-mode-of-hooks)” section.

In that example there is a `Counter` component that defines state (just a number) with the help of `useReducer` hook. Reducer handles only one action — `'tick'` on which it increments the state by the value of `step` prop. `'tick'` action is dispatched every second in interval function that is set up in `useEffect` hook once.
Here is the code from that example with some minor modifications:

```js
function Counter({ step }) {
    const [count, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, 0);

    function reducer(state, action) {
        if (action.type === "tick") {
            console.log(`Reducer: state=${state} and step=${step}`);
            return state + step;
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`);
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Create interval");
        const id = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Dispatch");
            dispatch({ type: "tick" });
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            console.log("Clear interval");
            clearInterval(id);
        };
    }, [dispatch]);

    return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}

function App() {
    const [step, setStep] = React.useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <Counter step={step} />
            <input
                type="number"
                value={step}
                onChange={(e) => setStep(Number(e.target.value))}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

What I found is that that example works on `react@16.8.0-alpha.0` and doesn't on `react@16.8.0`  and higher. When I run the code the initial value is `0` for both step and counter. If I wait for 3 seconds without changing anything and then increment the step I get the following output:

```
Create interval
Dispatch
Reducer: state=0 and step=0
Dispatch
Reducer: state=0 and step=0
Dispatch
Reducer: state=0 and step=0
Reducer: state=0 and step=1
Reducer: state=1 and step=1
Reducer: state=2 and step=1
Dispatch
Reducer: state=3 and step=1
Reducer: state=3 and step=1
Dispatch
Reducer: state=4 and step=1
Dispatch
Reducer: state=5 and step=1
```

As you can see by the logs the reducer is executed more than the `"tick"` action was dispatched.

I have managed to make it work as expected by creating a ref from `step` prop and memoizing the reducer with `useCallback` hook without any dependencies.

```js
const stepRef = React.useRef(step);
React.useEffect(() => {
  stepRef.current = step;
}, [step]);

const reducer = useCallback((state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "tick") {
    console.log(`Reducer: state=${state} and step=${stepRef.current}`);
    return state + stepRef.current;
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
}, []);
```

You can play with the examples here:

- [Buggy one from the article](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-reducer-hook-ewq5j) (if you change React version to `react@16.8.0-alpha.0` it will work as expected though);
- [Fixed one](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-reducer-hook-fixed-2e4zd) (works on both versions).

But the questions still stand.

1. What of those behaviours (`react@16.8.0-alpha.0` or `react@16.8.0`) of `useReducer` hook from the buggy example is considered correct in nowadays React?
2. Is it a bug?
3. If it's not a bug then why it works that way and reducer is triggered more than needed?

The answer to the last question should be somehow related to the the fact that reducer is being recreated. Be it on every render or even only when `step` prop changes it doesn't matter as memoizing the reducer with `useCallback` hook and passing `[step]` as a dependency array doesn't fix the problem. Does anyone have any ideas about that?

Thanks!

Comment: it's better to pass `step` in `action.payload` since reducers should be pure functions (you can then lift the reducer outside of the function component).

Comment: @marzelin Yeah, but that way `useEffect` hook will become dependent on `step` prop and this will cause the interval to get recreated every time `step` prop changes. That's what I would like to avoid.

Comment: `step` should be `ref`fed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useReducer` needs to remember `reducer` to be able to say whether a component needs a rerender (needs it to compute state and compare it with the previous one). But the reducer it has access to might be stale since you can "swap" the reducer. So, in the case when the reducer state is the same as the previous one, instead of throwing the result away and calling it a day React stashes the result as well as the reducer that was used to calculate it till the next re-render and then checks if the reducer is still the same. If not, the state is calculated again using the fresh reducer.

Your example is an edge case. It shouldn't work like that but React doesn't know when exactly it should throw away the stale reducer state updates - it always waits till the next rerender to compare reducers and compute the final state that will be used in re-render.

Here's a simplified example that depicts it:
Initially `step` is `0`. `dispatch` is run 3 times. The result is
`0 + 0 + 0 = 0`
and that's correctly displayed. Then, when you click on the button, `step` changes to `1` but `dispatch` isn't triggered even once. Nevertheless, the result is now `3` because all previous actions were re-run with a newly created reducer.

```js
function App() {
  console.log("rendering");
  
  const [step, setStep] = React.useState(0);
  
  const [count, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, 0);

  function reducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === "tick") {
      console.log(`Reducer: state=${state} and step=${step}`);
      return state + step;
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      console.log("Dispatch");
      dispatch({ type: "tick" });
    }
   
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      <span>{count}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => setStep(step + 1)}
      >step +1</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

The solution is to make the reducer pure (as it should be from the beginning) and pass all the required data in `action.payload` (`ref`ing things if needed).

```js
function reducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === "tick") {
      const { step } = action.payload;
      console.log(`Reducer: state=${state} and step=${step}`);
      return state + step;
    }
  }

function Counter({ step }) {
  const [count, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, 0);
  const stepRef = React.useRef();
  stepRef.current = step;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Create interval");
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Dispatch");
      dispatch({ type: "tick", payload: { step: stepRef.current }});
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log("Clear interval");
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <span>{count}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>;
}

function App() {
  const [step, setStep] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Counter step={step} />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={step}
        onChange={(e) => setStep(Number(e.target.value))}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In case newly created reducer's logic was somehow changed what's the point for React to rerun that reducer with all the actions that were dispatched for the previous reducer? What could possibly go wrong if there was no that "rerun" thing (as it is in `16.8.0.-alpha.0` AFAIU)? It seems like without that rerun `useReducer` would work as expected in both cases: when reducer is pure and impure. Am I wrong?

Comment: @savchenkoto alpha version was unoptimized, so rerender was triggered even if reducer's state didn't change - that's why the code works on that version. If it were as you want, consider a component where reducer depends on state, and in some event you call both `dispatch` and `setState`. If `dispatch` was called first it would use the stale state. In the current version order doesn't matter - reducer always gets the fresh state.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [step, setStep] = React.useState(0);

  function Counter({ step }) {
    const [count, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, 0);

    function reducer(state, action) {
      if (action.type === "tick") {
        console.log(`Reducer: state=${state} and step=${step}`);
        return step === 0 ? state : state + step;
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`);
      }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Create interval");
      const id = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("Dispatch");
        dispatch({ type: "tick" });
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        console.log("Clear interval");
        clearInterval(id);
      };
    }, [dispatch]);

    return <h1>{count}</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Counter step={step} />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={step}
        onChange={(e) => setStep(Number(e.target.value))}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```